# Cannot disable combo selects first value

Tags: extjs, combobox

I have a combo like below.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
            fieldLabel: 'Label',
            allowBlank: true,
            maxLength: 50,
            minChars: 10000,
            name: 'txt',
            id: 'txt',
            store: states,
            displayField: 'name',
            selectOnFocus: false,
            forceSelection: false,
            typeAhead: false,
            autoSelect: false,
            queryMode: 'local',
            triggerAction: 'all',
            hideTrigger: true,
            listeners: {
                beforequery: function (record) {
                    record.query = new RegExp(record.query, 'i');
                    record.forceAll = false;
                },
                specialkey: function (f, e) {
                    if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
                        doProcess();
                    }
                }
            },
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
```

My purpose to provide is building a textbox that remember history. I've searched and found this solution: You must use combo like textfield.
No problem so far.
But when I write something and select record from list that searched before, the next time combo selects it automatically while I write.
I'm not sure if I explained.

You can test it here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/28tl

Regards.

Comment: means do you want to deselect the last selected item from picker ?

Comment: What exactly you want.I cannot understand from your given information.

Comment: Right, I want to deselect combo item when I wrote something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I've solved my problem like below.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/28tl

This example tells me more clear than my question.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        // The data store containing the list of states
        var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
            data: [{
                "abbr": "AL",
                "name": "Alabama"
            }, {
                "abbr": "AK",
                "name": "Alaska"
            }, {
                "abbr": "AZ",
                "name": "Arizona"
            }]
        });

        // Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
        Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
            fieldLabel: 'Label',
            allowBlank: true,
            maxLength: 50,
            minChars: 10000,
            name: 'txt',
            id: 'txt',
            store: states,
            displayField: 'name',
            selectOnFocus: false,
            forceSelection: false,
            typeAhead: false,
            autoSelect: false,
            queryMode: 'local',
            triggerAction: 'all',
            hideTrigger: true,
            enableKeyEvents: true

            ,
            listConfig: {
                listeners: {
                    itemclick: function (list, record) {
                        _iseFareIleSecildi = true;
                    },
                    highlightitem: function (view, node, eOpts) {
                        _iseKlavyeIleSecildi = true;
                    }
                }
            },
            listeners: {
                beforequery: function (record) {
                    record.query = new RegExp(record.query, 'i');
                    record.forceAll = false;
                    Ext.defer(function () {
                        secimiSifirla();
                    }, 30);
                },
                specialkey: function (f, e) {
                    if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
                        console.log('action');
                    }
                },
                keyup: function (combo, e) {
                    if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
                        console.log('action');
                    }
                },
                beforeselect: function (combo, record, index, eOpts) {
                    if (_iseFareIleSecildi) {
                        secimiSifirla();
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        if (_iseKlavyeIleSecildi) {
                            secimiSifirla();
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }

});

var _iseFareIleSecildi = false;
var _iseKlavyeIleSecildi = false;

function secimiSifirla() {
    _iseFareIleSecildi = false;
    _iseKlavyeIleSecildi = false;
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [trackOver](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.view.BoundList.html#cfg-trackOver) boundlist config to `false` like so:

```
xtype: 'combo',
...
listConfig: {
    trackOver: false
}
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2945

Comment: Hi, I think I've could not explain. 
When I select "Alabama" and then BACKSPACE from keyboard for example ALABAM->ALABA->ALAB and hit enter combo automatically selects "ALABAMA" 
But I don't want this behaviour.
Combo should only filter but not select the item.
How can I achieve this?

If you try your fiddle sample you cannot prevent to auto-complete to previous selection.
Sorry my English.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try with "tagfield". [Check here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/g9n&view/editor)

Comment: Thanks but it has not got same behaviour that I need.
This is a search box and I do not want to tag style. And also ıt does not behaves that I expect.
Regards.